# ASP.NET MVC and .NET 3.5 SP1 on Windows Server 2003 and IIS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-server-2003, .net-3.5

I am writing a website for a client who says their servers run the following: "Windows 2003 with the latest IIS".  What do I need to do to get them ready for hosting my ASP.NET MVC website built with .NET 3.5SP1?

Answer (score 11):

You'll probably also run into an issue with IIS6 on Win2k3.  Phil Haack posts an excellent walkthrough on his blog [Asp.Net MVC on IIS 6 Walkthrough](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx).

You'll also need the following prereqs:

- [.Net 3.5 SP1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/products/cc533447.aspx)
- [Asp.Net MVC Beta](http://www.asp.net/MVC/)

Answer (score 1):

Just have them install .Net 3.5 SP1 redist.

**EDIT** They will of coarse have to create the virtual directory for your web app, create an application on that directory, give proper permissions, and possibly manually set the ASP.Net to the v2.0.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 2003 with the latest IIS? Well,this isn't really possible since you can't run IIS7 on Windows Server 2003. You'll need to upgrade to Windows Server 2008 in order to run the latest IIS.

That said, if you are running IIS6, you have to jump through some hoops. There are a couple of best practices (Url file extensions or wild card application maps) which [Phil Haack has well documented](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/26/asp.net-mvc-on-iis-6-walkthrough.aspx) which will help to get your application running correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to bin-deploy MVC, just install .NET 3.5 SP1. If you want to get MVC installed in the GAC, they should install the MVC beta as well.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Web Setup project and add .net 3.5 as a prerequisite.  The installer asks what virtual directory to install to.